# [AxiosError : {message: 'User validation failed: gender: Path `gender` is required.''}.]. I'm using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

This's my first time using MongoDB. I'm making REST API on server side with Node.Js, all this API totally works fine on my Postman. I have no trouble when I tried to input a value to MongoDB from **Text Field** but when I'm used **Select Box** the troubles come & I'm stuck with this, please help.

**Error That I got**
`` AxiosError code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", message: "Request failed with status code 400", data: {message: 'User validation failed: gender: Path `gender` is required.'} ``

**My Select Box**

```
<div className='form-group col'>
 <select
    class="form-select form-select-sm"
    value={gender}
    onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}
    required>
      <option disabled selected aria-hidden>--Select Gender--</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

**My Save Function**

```
const saveUser = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user", {
      name,
      email,
      gender
  });
    navigate("/lists")
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

**My API Function**

```
export const saveUser = async (req, res) => {
const user = new User(req.body);
try {
    const inserteduser = await user.save();
    res.status(201).json(inserteduser);
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
}
```

}

**My DB Model**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
    
    const User = mongoose.Schema({
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        gender:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    });
    
    export default mongoose.model('User', User);
```

I have no trouble when tried to pass some value using text field, but I think because I'm using **Select Box**. Maybe there's something I've been missing or wrong let me know.

Comment: try to `console.log` the data before you save it to MongoDB and see if `gender` is not empty

Comment: Or just change required: false on the gender object , and check the value on the MongoDb

Comment: I just found the problem, the value `gender` that have been passed from `select box` is empty, but if I pass that value from `text field` its just working fine. I already set the value but how the outcome is empty? @mocherfaoui

Comment: I can save the data if I set `required : false`. And I found the problem there, because the value just not passed from `select box`. How do I show the value from `select box`, because I already set the value there but just not get read? @HakobSargsyan

Comment: Can you show me where you are calling saveUser for jsx @DanuPratama

Comment: I just fix that, I make another `const` that pass the data first. So the data get stored first at `array object`. And then I just passed that data to the `axios` and get stored to mongoDB. Anyway many thanks @HakobSargsyan

Comment: I just fix that, I make another `const` that pass the data first. So the data get stored first at `array object`. And then I just passed that data to the `axios` and get stored to mongoDB. Anyway many thanks @mocherfaoui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed this. The problem is the value that had been pass from the **select box** is empty. So I store the data first with another `const`.

**const to store the data temporary**

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
   name: '',
   email: '',
   gender: ''
});
```

**And the function to handle the onchange event**

```
function handle(e) {
  const newData = { ...data };
  newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
  setData(newData);
  console.log(newData);
};
```

**And this how I pass the value from the data array**

```
const saveUser = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
try {
  await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user", {
    name: data.name,
    email: data.email,
    gender: data.gender
  })
  .then(console.log(data));
  navigate("/lists")
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
}
```

**This how I get the value from the select box**

```
    <select
       id='gender'
       className="form-select form-select-sm"
       value={data.gender}
       onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
       required>
         <option selected hidden>--Select Gender--</option>
         <option value="Male">Male</option>
         <option value="Female">Female</option>
     </select>
```